# Client Server Sync Scenario

Tags: mysql, client-server, synchronization

I have one table at server side and client side. There are multiple clients.

Fields of table at server are `"ID"` and `"Name"`

Fields of table at client are `"ID"`, `"Server_ID"`, `"Name"` and `"Sync"`

Now the **scenario is :**

I send row to server and store row at server database and server send response to client with Server_ID and then i store that row at client database.

**Question :** What if row is stored successfully at server database but network connection lost and response did not reached at client side?

How to handle this case? How server knows that client did not get response?

Comment: ever looked into replication?

Comment: yes but did not get much help